# Android studio failing to load resource

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-resources

While trying to implement a spinner in a view for an alertDialog, Android Studio is returning the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol @string/categoryOptions
```

I am trying to populate a spinner class:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/category"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@string/categoryOptions"
/>
```

Using the following string array in res/values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="categoryOptions">
<item>Stream or Lake</item>
<item>Well</item>
<item>Gov. Facility</item>
<item>Spring</item>
</string-array>
...
</resources>
```

I can access other plain string objects in the strings resource file, but not the string-array. It's completely possible that I have a syntax error somewhere and just am not seeing it, but I don't think that is the issue. Please help.

Comment: Just kidding. Turns out coding android on 3.5 hours of sleep makes me miss simple things like the fact that "categoryOptions" is an array, not a string. Therefore, the spinner should have `android:entries="@`**array**`/categoryOptions"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
android:entries="@array/categoryOptions"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the array like:

```
 String[] array_str = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categoryOptions);
```

and then for spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.mySpinner, array_str); 
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check my earlier comment, you'll notice I found my error, which can only be described as a rookie mistake. Hurray for sleep deprivation. Thanks guys!

Solution:

Use `android:entries="@` **array** `/categoryOptions"`

Instead of `android:entries="@string/categoryOptions"`